# Azure Function - Service Bus Topic Trigger - local debugging intermittently stops working for periods of time

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-function-app

I'm developing a service bus topic trigger azure function in visual studio 2019. I debug it locally the same way as any other application, Debug -> Start new instance.

When I debug locally, about 70% of the time it works perfectly. I can trigger a message into the target topic, and the visual studio debugger picks it up just fine and i can debug breakpoints within the azure function, etc.

However, the other 30% of the time, nothing happens. No breakpoints hit, no information in the console, nothing. I typically just end up waiting a couple hours and trying again, and then it will work.

Does anyone have any input for me on how i can go about investigating what is causing this intermittent inability to debug locally? Let me know if there is any extra information I can provide that would help diagnose this issue. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is the lock duration configured ? When the trigger picks up a message it is locked for a certain amount of time, when you stop debugging, the message is not released and stay locked. That would be my first guess.

Comment: Is this lock duration something I configure on my azure function itself, or the service bus? Because the service bus I am consuming i do not have direct control over, so changing those settings will be more challenging. But thanks for the tip I will look into that further.

Comment: it s a property of the topic/subscription on azure.